# Firefox sync error when using own sync server

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox, firefox-sync

I'm using Firefox Sync (née Weave) syncing with my own server. Some time ago - perhaps when updated to FF Sync 1.6, but I'm not sure - the sync stopped working.

The errors I'm getting are "Error While Signing In" and "Wrong sync key. Please try again." I know my Passphrase and I can see My Sync Key in the preferences but have no idea about the sync key I'm supposed to use. I currently have no installation of FF that successfully syncs.

What kind of conversion the newer Add-on has done to the encryption key or should I do something myself because I'm syncing against my own server?

I've read some articles about the controversies about Passphrase and Sync key, but to no avail. How do I get my browsers back in sync?

Comment: Not an answer really but I see similar issues when googling the problem, and it sounds like Firefox Sync just isn't a great solution for a lot of people. If you're looking for bookmark syncing, I find xmarks to be very reliable. Rumors of its demise were exaggerated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when Weave upgraded to 1.6, it changed it's structure and lost back compatibility. One had to upgrade the server properly before resuming syncing with the new version.
Also, 1.6 [introduced auto generation of the sync key](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/mobile/addon/firefox-sync/versions/) which might have overridden your old key. I recommend to start anew or use Mozilla's servers; as Sync anyways encrypts everything on the client PC itself before sending (So security isn't a big issue).